# How to safely deploy an ASP.NET server application together with a desktop client WinForms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, deployment

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 server application that works with SQL Server and that exposes some REST API for client consumption.

At the same time I have a Windows Forms application that consumes those REST services. The client application is being deployed through Click-Once.

Sometimes we make changes to the server that can break the client. It's not happening that often but it does happen from time to time.

I have been looking for a strategy to update both the client and server applications but so far I have not yet found a good one.

Ideally I'd like to do something along those lines:

- Backup the database
- Backup the server application
- Backup the client application
- Build the server application
- Build the client application
- Run the database migrations
- Publish the server application
- Publish the client application
- If anything fails, rollback

Right now I'm doing all that by hand and it's tedious and prone to errors.

- The migrations are being run through PowerShell using the commandlets of the EntityFramework (Database-Update)
- The server and client code is being built on a dev box and published through the "Publish..." function of Visual Studio

There are many things that can go wrong.. migrations failing, timeouts during publishing, etc...

Ideally I could move the build and publish steps to one of the production boxes so that once the applications are being compiled and linked I can just copy the files over to the correct folders and restart IIS.

I would really love to get some suggestions to improve the flow and make it as automatic as possible. Cheers!